# change space to underscore in filename using C

Tags: c, file

I have written my first C program that renames spaces in filenames to underscores. I wonder if there is an easier or more efficient way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    if ( argc != 2 ) {
        printf("Format is: NoSpace <filename>\n");
        return(0);
    }
    else if ( strstr( argv[1], " ") == NULL) {
        printf("No space character in file: %s\n",argv[1]);
        return(0);
    }

    int filename_size = strlen(argv[1]);
    char file_name_old[filename_size], file_name_new[filename_size];

    strcpy(file_name_old, argv[1]);
    strcpy(file_name_new, argv[1]);

    // ASCII 32 = space; ACII 95 = underscore
    for( int pos = 0; pos < filename_size; pos++) {
        if ( file_name_new[pos] == 32)  {
            file_name_new[pos] = 95;
        }
    }

    rename(file_name_old,file_name_new);
    return(0);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @RoiHatam you are not really making sense here... your comment seems more about using files with spaces in some specific console environment rather than about renaming files.

Comment: Regarding the code: why use 32 and 95 instead of `' '` and `'_'`? Also, your program will not play nice with full qualified path input like `"/user/home/My Awesome Folder/My File with Space to be replaced"`

Comment: You can use `strchr` to search for a particular character in a string to make the code slightly simpler, but you've got it about as efficient as possible.

Comment: The length of a C string is `strlen() + 1` to account for the terminating `'\0'` character.  These are too short:      `char file_name_old[filename_size], file_name_new[filename_size];`  And you need to check the return value from `rename()` and not ignore it.

Comment: If you like shorthand (or don't like to type), you can replace `strstr( argv[1], " ") == NULL` with simply `!strstr( argv[1], " ")`. Entirely up to  you.

Comment: @grek40 The for routine goes through all the characters in the file name and replaces ' ' with '_'. All the spaces will be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Report errors to error output stream

Error messages should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  We should also return a non-zero value when we fail - ideally `EXIT_FAILURE`, defined in `<stdlib.h>`:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Note also that I've interpolated `argv[0]`, so as to print the actual name we were invoked as, rather than having to match the code and the build system.

## Accept many arguments

Users would like to be able to operate on multiple files at once:

```sh
NoSpace *
```

We can support this (and I've hinted at this above, if you spotted the test `argc < 2`) by looping over the arguments:

```
for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
    const char *const src = argv[i];
    unspace(src);
}
```

## No-action-required is not an error

Possibly an opinion point, but I would suggest that a file that doesn't need any replacement shouldn't be considered a failure.

## Avoid overwriting existing files

We don't want to accidentally destroy data if the target filename already exists.  For Linux, we can avoid this without risk of a race between checking and acting by using the `renameat2()` system call:

```
    renameat2(AT_FDCWD, file_name_old, AT_FDCWD, file_name_new, RENAME_NOREPLACE);
```

## Buffer size (BUG)

We allocate `strlen(src)` characters as buffer, but we need one more, to account for the terminating NUL character.  Note that `strlen` returns a `size_t`, not an `int` (although it's unlikely to make a practical difference here).

## Replace during copy

We can perform the substitution as we copy:

```
    char *const src = argv[i];
    size_t filename_size = strlen(argv[i]);
    char dest[filename_size+1];
    for (char *p = src, *q = dest;  *p;  ++p, ++q)
        if (*p == ' ')
            *q = '_';
        else
            *q = *p;
    dest[filename_size] = '\0';
```

More compactly:

```
    for (char *p = src, *q = dest;  *p;  ++p, ++q)
        *q = *p == ' ' ? '_' : *p;
```

Note that we use character constants `' '` and `'_'`, so our code works in non-ASCII environments and so that its intention is clear without needing comments.

## Check the result of the `rename()` call

The library call may fail - perhaps the destination name exists (and we're using the `RENAME_NOREPLACE` flag), or the directory is not writable.

```
    if (renameat2(AT_FDCWD, src, AT_FDCWD, dest, RENAME_NOREPLACE)) {
        perror(src);
    }
```

We can make this more portable, by testing whether it's supported:

```
#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
#define rename(src, dest)  renameat2(AT_FDCWD, src, AT_FDCWD, dest, RENAME_NOREPLACE);
#endif
```

---

## Complete program

```
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
#define rename(src, dest)  renameat2(AT_FDCWD, src, AT_FDCWD, dest, RENAME_NOREPLACE);
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int ret_val = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        char *const src = argv[i];
        size_t filename_size = strlen(argv[i]);
        char dest[filename_size+1];
        for (char *p = src, *q = dest;  *p;  ++p, ++q)
            *q = *p == ' ' ? '_' : *p;
        dest[filename_size] = '\0';

        if (rename(src, dest)) {
            perror(src);
            ret_val = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

---

## Enhancement suggestions

You might want to look into accepting some option flags to adjust behaviour.  I suggest the following (modelled on the `mv` command):

- `-v` for verbose output: print a line for every file successfully moved
- `-f` to overwrite existing files without checking
- `-i` to ask before overwriting an existing file

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and complex answer! I will work on it and read the documentation about these improvements. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Although this indeed does something similar to your goal, here are some criticisms / improvements:

1. There's absolutely no need to take a copy of the original filename.
2. If you meet an error condition, return 1 (or better `EXIT_FAILURE` from `stdlib.h`), so scripts calling your tool get a chance to detect the error.
3. Use functions; this helps your code to keep structure
4. Your tool will not work correctly for filenames with paths, so better search from the end and stop replacing when you hit a path separator character.
5. When iterating through a string, it's often easier to just use pointers instead of array indexing.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#define isPathSep(x) ((x) == '\\' || (x) == '/')
#else
#define isPathSep(x) ((x) == '/')
#endif

char *sanitizeFileName(const char *filename)
{
    size_t namelen = strlen(filename);

    char *sanitized = malloc(namelen + 1);
    if (!sanitized)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(sanitized, filename);

    char *p = sanitized + namelen - 1;
    while (p >= sanitized)
    {
        if (isPathSep(*p)) break;
        if (*p == ' ') *p = '_';
        --p;
    }

    return sanitized;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [filename]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *safename = sanitizeFileName(argv[1]);

    // instead of rename(), for demonstration:
    printf("%s -> %s\n", argv[1], safename);

    free(safename);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: char *sanitized = strdup(filename);  might be a better choice than strlen() and strcpy(). I'd also use strrchr('/') to find the last slash in the file name, increment the pointer returned by strrchr('/') and then go forward rather than backwards with pointer p. The algorithm you have is a good one.

Comment: @pacmaninbw - true, where `strdup()` is available - it's not a standard C function.

Comment: @TobySpeight I guess I've always been lucky, I've never had a problem with it in 30 years, but you're correct that's what my search just turned up.

Comment: @pacmaninbw with the GNU toolchain, you can compile with e.g. `-std=c11` to only get declarations of standard c by default, helps a lot for writing portable code

Comment: Actually, for user input in windows, both separators `/` and `\` should be expected.

Comment: good catch, see edit ...

Answer (score 3):

This code is correct. Here some style tips for you:

1. I recommend to get rid of the `file_name_old`. In this program, you never edit it anyway and rename accepts const chars (never will be edited inside this function), so you can replace this:

   ```
   rename(file_name_old,file_name_new);
   ```

   With this:

   ```
   rename(argv[1], file_name_new);
   ```
2. Replace "magic numbers" in this scope:

   ```
   if ( file_name_new[pos] == 32)  {
       file_name_new[pos] = 95;
   }
   ```

   With this:

   ```
   if ( file_name_new[pos] == ' ')  {
       file_name_new[pos] = '_';
   }
   ```
3. As commenters pointed out, use `strlen(argv[1]) + 1` when declaring new arrays.

Answer (score 3):

#### Buffer overrun

You allocated one too few bytes in each of your filenames, because you forgot about the terminating null character:

> ```
> int filename_size = strlen(argv[1]);
> char file_name_old[filename_size], file_name_new[filename_size];
>
> strcpy(file_name_old, argv[1]);
> strcpy(file_name_new, argv[1]);
> ```

You could either change the size to include that extra byte:

```
 int filename_size = strlen(argv[1]) + 1;
```

Or you could allocate one more byte here:

```
 char file_name_new[filename_size+1];
```

(Note: I removed `file_name_old` because it was a useless copy)